# dplyr::left_join() produces an unexpected error

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join

I have

```
> head(p)
  studie    sex n_fjernet n_sygdom
1 Group1   Male        22        1
2 Group1   Male        61        2
3 Group1 Female        50        1
4 Group1 Female        47        3
5 Group1 Female        30        1
6 Group1 Female        60        0
```

and

```
> head(u)
  studie alder    sex n_fjernet n_sygdom n_otte
1 Group4    59 Female        26        0      0
2 Group4    85   Male         7        1      1
3 Group4    74 Female        17        9      6
4 Group4    78   Male        13        0      0
5 Group4    41   Male        11        0      0
6 Group4    62   Male        12        0      0
```

I want to add `u$n_otte` to `p` for all cases of `p$studie==u$studie`**and**`p$sex==u$sex`**and**`p$n_fjernet==u$n_fjernet`**and**`p$n_sygdom==u$n_sygdom`, which is `895` cases in `u` out of the total of `1485` cases in `p`. All cases in `p` that does not match and gets `u$n_otte` `left_joined()`, should just be listed as `NA`

So I wrote

```
left_join(p, u %>% distinct(studie, sex, n_fjernet, n_sygdom, .keep_all = TRUE), by = "n_otte")
```

Which returned an error

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `n_otte` which is missing from LHS
```

I tried different `left_join()` approaches but all returned an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
u <- structure(list(studie = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Group4", 
"Group3"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), n_fjernet = c(26L, 
7L, 17L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 8L, 35L, 23L, 5L, 20L, 11L, 
5L, 30L, 12L, 23L, 37L, 13L, 26L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 39L, 13L, 
5L, 9L, 19L, 32L, 18L, 16L, 45L, 35L, 25L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 11L, 
44L, 20L, 48L, 92L, 6L, 29L, 12L, 26L, 37L, 30L, 54L, 32L, 39L, 
15L, 21L, 22L, 34L, 39L, 30L, 36L, 19L, 26L, 43L, 26L, 42L, 18L, 
15L, 32L, 29L, 36L, 28L, 38L, 35L, 66L, 11L, 49L, 32L, 61L, 49L, 
36L, 51L, 42L, 13L, 10L, 36L, 45L, 49L, 52L, 21L, 42L, 29L, 38L, 
28L, 37L, 47L, 33L, 50L, 19L, 45L, 23L, 29L, 31L, 59L, 60L, 32L, 
32L, 30L, 50L, 29L, 32L, 42L, 24L, 22L, 47L, 24L, 22L, 8L, 38L, 
25L, 34L, 45L, 50L, 51L, 28L, 8L, 21L, 17L, 30L, 36L, 20L, 56L, 
23L, 77L, 23L, 76L, 58L, 35L, 33L, 52L, 34L, 17L, 66L, 38L, 58L, 
16L, 58L, 44L, 22L, 42L, 17L, 33L, 9L, 31L, 15L, 46L, 31L, 32L, 
25L, 17L, 31L, 35L, 29L, 18L, 69L, 28L, 25L, 35L, 19L, 18L, 15L, 
51L, 41L, 55L, 35L, 19L, 45L, 24L, 39L, 57L, 45L, 37L, 30L, 33L, 
34L, 47L, 21L, 16L, 22L, 26L, 36L, 32L, 17L, 28L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 
30L, 32L, 29L, 41L, 18L, 26L, 32L, 30L, 17L, 35L, 17L, 27L, 27L, 
10L, 30L, 50L, 28L, 22L, 13L, 32L, 35L, 51L, 44L, 16L, 17L, 43L, 
27L, 21L, 34L, 13L, 18L, 37L, 20L, 8L, 19L, 43L, 24L, 48L, 15L, 
11L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 12L, 31L, 28L, 34L, 25L, 22L, 38L, 
28L, 26L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 39L, 22L, 41L, 14L, 60L, 35L, 10L, 29L, 
24L, 25L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 10L, 32L, 30L, 34L, 31L, 
24L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 31L, 33L, 15L, 27L, 19L, 40L, 17L, 48L, 35L, 
25L, 25L, 22L, 19L, 24L, 20L, 30L, 13L, 28L, 19L, 7L, 29L, 18L, 
41L, 11L, 42L, 35L, 24L, 16L, 29L, 39L, 28L, 32L, 16L, 31L, 30L, 
27L, 17L, 28L, 29L, 12L, 25L, 30L, 14L, 19L, 13L, 32L, 16L, 12L, 
24L, 10L, 34L, 49L, 17L, 11L, 37L, 38L, 36L, 18L, 42L, 14L, 33L, 
41L, 21L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 32L, 25L, 22L, 19L, 28L, 16L, 24L, 
28L, 29L, 34L, 27L, 23L, 33L, 23L, 57L, 30L, 16L, 13L, 20L, 42L, 
14L, 18L, 31L, 19L, 22L, 27L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 25L, 29L, 35L, 21L, 
64L, 39L, 51L, 21L, 16L, 36L, 22L, 15L, 29L, 38L, 20L, 23L, 5L, 
33L, 15L, 20L, 52L, 31L, 16L, 10L, 12L, 47L, 23L, 28L, 27L, 18L, 
24L, 34L, 45L, 24L, 43L, 28L, 34L, 20L, 26L, 17L, 41L, 25L, 38L, 
35L, 25L, 21L, 24L, 21L, 24L, 14L, 40L, 19L, 11L, 21L, 38L, 43L, 
23L, 28L, 17L, 78L, 12L, 27L, 16L, 24L, 16L, 21L, 43L, 25L, 50L, 
44L, 30L, 33L, 31L, 20L, 47L, 47L, 34L, 22L, 31L, 28L, 51L, 23L, 
45L, 30L, 34L, 32L, 39L, 41L, 25L, 15L, 19L, 14L, 41L, 40L, 49L, 
27L, 35L, 26L, 22L, 59L, 10L, 29L, 38L, 64L, 16L, 36L, 56L, 31L, 
50L, 23L, 27L, 49L, 30L, 28L, 25L, 38L, 37L, 25L, 30L, 23L, 18L, 
31L, 48L, 47L, 49L), n_sygdom = c(0L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 16L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 14L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 
6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 16L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), n_otte = c(0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 
3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 
3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 
6L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 
0L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 
0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")
```

And

```
p <- structure(list(studie = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Group2", 
"Group3", "Group4"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    n_fjernet = c(18L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 41L, 31L, 13L, 41L, 25L, 
    16L, 18L, 26L, 35L, 36L, 22L, 20L, 16L, 10L, 19L, 46L, 6L, 
    49L, 70L, 46L, 55L, 25L, 22L, 37L, 28L, 52L, 27L, 15L, 11L, 
    7L, 24L, 11L, 56L, 47L, 27L, 14L, 16L, 21L, 43L, 25L, 50L, 
    44L, 30L, 33L, 31L, 20L, 47L, 47L, 34L, 22L, 31L, 28L, 51L, 
    23L, 45L, 30L, 34L, 32L, 39L, 41L, 25L, 15L, 19L, 14L, 41L, 
    40L, 49L, 27L, 35L, 26L, 22L, 59L, 10L, 29L, 38L, 64L, 16L, 
    36L, 56L, 31L, 50L, 23L, 27L, 49L, 30L, 28L, 25L, 38L, 37L, 
    25L, 30L, 23L, 18L, 31L, 48L, 47L, 49L, 38L, 19L, 3L, 69L, 
    26L, 30L, 57L, 52L, 40L, 32L, 17L, 42L, 32L, 15L, 63L, 25L, 
    29L, 45L, 49L, 27L, 21L, 43L, 31L, 13L, 22L, 28L, 45L, 24L, 
    17L, 49L, 34L, 61L, 51L, 51L, 29L, 32L, 23L, 9L, 14L, 28L, 
    35L, 43L, 46L, 32L, 52L, 22L, 34L, 66L, 27L, 59L, 31L, 27L, 
    34L, 38L, 69L, 50L, 63L, 48L, 37L, 41L, 31L, 48L, 35L, 36L, 
    30L, 38L, 39L, 22L, 97L, 19L, 29L, 72L, 25L, 113L, 17L, 62L, 
    29L, 44L, 24L, 20L, 48L, 66L, 30L, 24L, 19L, 42L, 27L, 87L, 
    24L, 19L, 45L, 30L, 34L, 57L, 51L, 28L, 26L, 40L, 102L, 23L, 
    54L, 32L, 18L, 22L, 4L, 40L, 56L, 3L, 34L, 46L, 29L, 14L, 
    33L, 52L, 15L, 33L, 44L, 25L, 35L, 33L, 45L, 50L, 38L, 33L, 
    24L, 45L, 61L, 17L, 38L, 18L, 65L, 61L, 19L, 19L, 25L, 68L, 
    39L, 21L, 18L, 39L, 36L, 46L, 35L, 68L, 18L, 14L, 18L, 28L, 
    55L, 30L, 40L, 57L, 52L, 91L, 60L, 84L, 92L, 26L, 65L, 39L, 
    73L, 36L, 33L, 51L, 133L, 66L, 62L, 38L, 53L, 70L, 33L, 20L, 
    52L, 45L, 64L, 106L, 70L, 24L, 23L, 44L, 35L, 31L, 52L, 46L, 
    33L, 15L, 42L, 35L, 33L, 19L, 54L, 64L, 37L, 27L, 51L, 27L, 
    52L, 61L, 38L, 31L, 46L, 86L, 44L, 58L, 32L, 27L, 13L, 12L, 
    38L, 72L, 20L, 59L, 37L, 27L, 23L, 59L, 36L, 28L, 38L, 26L, 
    64L, 34L, 38L, 21L, 34L, 44L, 33L, 55L, 38L, 51L, 49L, 45L, 
    44L, 40L, 33L, 19L, 18L, 45L, 52L, 63L, 16L, 24L, 50L, 59L, 
    98L, 60L, 63L, 49L, 59L, 35L, 35L, 38L, 56L, 78L, 68L, 56L, 
    42L, 80L, 58L, 39L, 50L, 17L, 37L, 40L, 22L, 51L, 32L, 34L, 
    17L, 33L, 18L, 33L, 25L, 4L, 57L, 47L, 27L, 33L, 20L, 42L, 
    29L, 41L, 22L, 17L, 9L, 17L, 39L, 78L, 19L, 37L, 50L, 34L, 
    14L, 29L, 49L, 25L, 33L, 54L, 47L, 12L, 18L, 30L, 22L, 33L, 
    52L, 80L, 20L, 33L, 61L, 34L, 36L, 67L, 35L, 36L, 24L, 12L, 
    47L, 29L, 38L, 30L, 25L, 19L, 28L, 37L, 72L, 31L, 39L, 36L, 
    30L, 60L, 45L, 29L, 56L, 44L, 124L, 42L, 39L, 26L, 74L, 25L, 
    25L, 124L, 32L, 28L, 32L, 9L, 21L, 25L, 24L, 40L, 14L, 42L, 
    49L, 21L, 28L, 44L, 38L, 24L, 28L, 34L, 26L, 46L, 36L, 31L, 
    39L, 22L, 80L, 37L, 54L, 19L, 14L, 55L, 42L, 45L, 23L, 31L, 
    21L, 33L, 25L, 18L, 46L, 22L, 54L, 32L, 28L, 28L, 31L, 28L, 
    29L, 41L, 34L, 24L, 41L, 32L, 39L, 14L, 32L, 46L, 32L), n_sygdom = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 
    3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 16L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 
    8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
    9L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 22L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
    8L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You are trying to join by n_otte. Just remove the by part of your join and it will join on all of the matching columns. `left_join(p, u %>% distinct(studie, sex, n_fjernet, n_sygdom, .keep_all = TRUE))`

Comment: Isn't the error obvious? Your code is trying to join by a column, which is not even there in LHS. Since you are trying to add the `n_otte` column, that will not be the `by` argument. `by` should contain those columns which can be used to match observations from two data frames.

Comment: It returns this because that is how language & library work. Please say what you expect & why at the first subexpression with unexpected result or we can't address your misconceptions & you are just asking for yet another presentation of documentation without us knowing what would help you better than any other one. Please give *minimal* code & data in a [mre]. Please reflect your research.

Comment: We can expect this is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge(p, u, by = c('studie', 'sex', 'n_fjernet', 'n_sygdom'), all.x = T)
```

or

```
p %>% 
    left_join(., u, by = c('studie', 'sex', 'n_fjernet', 'n_sygdom'))
```

Comment: An explanation on why this works wouldn't hurt. Code only answers are many times flagged as VLQ.